# Cannot remove white space below footer

Tags: css, whitespace, footer

I have a big bar of white space below my footer and cant figure out how to remove it. Basically I want everything below the footer to be gone.

Any help appreciated, just learning code so new to this.

https://jsfiddle.net/ptgL5pv6/1/

```js
function active() {
  var search_bar = document.getElementById('search_bar');
  if (search_bar.value == 'Search') {
    search_bar.value = '';
    search_bar.placeholder = 'Search';
  }
}

function inactive() {
  var search_bar = document.getElementById('search_bar');
  if (search_bar.value == '') {
    search_bar.value = 'Search';
    search_bar.placeholder = '';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {}

.top_section {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first_image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar {
  background: #222b2f;
  border: 10px solid #222B2F;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  Text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav_bar a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  Text-decoration: underline;
}

.third_bar {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}

.second_image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 370px;
}

#search_bar {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  width: 800px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-botton-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  right: 110px;
}

#search_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 222px;
  height: 172px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1d826;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-botton-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  left: 710px;
}

#search_button:hover {
  background: #f6e049;
}

.form {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -220px;
  padding-left: 280px;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: -10px;
}

.copyright {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer_notes {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top_section">
    <div class="first_image">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav_bar">
    <a href="#"> Home</a>
    <a href="#"> Search</a>
    <a href="#"> About us</a>
    <a href="#"> Products & Pricing</a>
    <a href="#"> Contact us</a>
    <a href="#"> login</a>
  </div>

  <div class="third_bar">
    <div class="second_image">
      <img src="whisky.png">
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="" value="Search for your whisky here" max length="30" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();" />
        <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go!" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
      &copy test.com &reg
    </div>
    <div class="footer_notes">
      test.com is a one of a kind fully automated and repsosive database of over 40,000 items. Second to none on ther Internet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.docdroid.net/yFeUlnJ/code-test.txt.html

Comment: For the sake of everyone else: https://jsfiddle.net/ptgL5pv6/1/

Comment: Any css reset like `* { padding :0 ; margin :0 } `

Comment: where would that go? , sorry new to coding and learning the hard way. It appears to be the form that is causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firt of all, edit this `.footer-notes` css and remove `left:100px;` from it. It is making your page width greater then 100%

```
.footer_notes{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

then dont declare height on `.third-bar` this makes your footer come up even if their is content above the footer

```
.third_bar{
    background:#000000;
    position: relative;
}
```

Even after doing this your footer will have maybe 20px or so space below it because their is not enough content above it. If you want your footer to always stay at bottom in any device then add this to your footer's css.

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

If you go through with all three changes this is what your page will look like :

```js
function active(){ 
  var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar'); 
 if(search_bar.value == 'Search'){ 
 search_bar.value='' 
 search_bar.placeholder= 'Search' 
 }  
} 

 function inactive(){ 
  var search_bar= document.getElementById('search_bar'); 
 if(search_bar.value == ''){ 
 search_bar.value='Search' 
 search_bar.placeholder= '' 
 }  
}
```

```css
body {
 background: #efefef;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}

#container{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 height:100vh;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color:black
}

.top_section {
 background:#000000;
 padding: 20px;
}

.first_image{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav_bar {
 background: #222b2f;
 border: 10px; solid #222B2F;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar a{
 position: relative;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
}

.nav_bar a:hover{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

.third_bar{
 background:#000000;
 position: relative;

}

.second_image{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 height:80vh;
 background-image: url("http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg");
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}

#search_bar
{
 position: relative;
 bottom: 50px;
 height: 150px;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 border-right: none;
 font-size: 36px;
 padding: 10px;
 outline:none;
 width: 800px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-botton-left-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 right:110px;
}

#search_button
{
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 bottom: 222px;
 height: 172px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 font-size: 36px;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #f1d826;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-botton-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 left: 710px;
}

#search_button:hover
{
background:#f6e049;
}



.form{
 width:200px;
 margin-top: -300px;
 padding-left:280px;

}

.footer
{
 position: fixed;
 background: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;

}
.copyright
{
position: relative;
bottom: -8px;
left: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.footer_notes

{

position: relative;
text-align: center;
bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 100px;
overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"> 

 <div class="top_section"> 
  <div class="first_image"> 
  <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a> 
  </div> 
 </div> 

 <div class="nav_bar"> 
 <a href ="#"> Home</a> 
 <a href ="#"> Search</a> 
 <a href ="#"> About us</a> 
 <a href ="#"> Products & Pricing</a> 
 <a href ="#"> Contact us</a> 
 <a href ="#"> login</a> 
 </div> 

 <div class="third_bar"> 
  <div class="second_image"> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form"><form action= "search.php" method="post"> 
   <input type="text" id="search_bar" placeholder="" value="Search for your whisky here" max length="30" autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();"/><input type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go!"/> 
   </form>  
   </div> 
 </div> 
    
 <div class="footer"> 
  <div class="copyright"> 
  &copy test.com &reg 
  </div> 
  <div class="footer_notes"> 
  test.com is a one of a kind fully automated and repsosive database of over 40,000 items. Second to none on ther Internet. 
  </div> 
 </div> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much. Really appreciate that. What a great forum. One last question. Behind the search bar I have an image "whisky.png" , there is a black space between the bottom of the image and the fixed footer. If I could remove the Black space then the whole page would be shown and there be be no scrolling. Your problem really helped and I thank you, If I could just remove the black space it would be perfect. Not sure how best to explain it, but attached a picture as below https://postimg.org/image/y71p3n79r/

Comment: Sorry, I tok some time to see the comment. I am going to take a look at it. can wait, maybe 10-15 minutes

Comment: Hi , of course. No problem. I appreciate the help and have no problem waiting at all. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer.I made some changes in html and css. I removed whisky.png and used background property for second_image column.

Comment: I haven't checked on bigger desktop sizes but if the space appers on bigger desktops (>1250px) then change height of `.second_image` from 80vh to 85vh or 90vh. If it works good for you, Please do accept my answer

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Really really appreciate that. I removed the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and replaced is with the script I have before, as it dropped the onMouseDown="active() , I am guessing that is ok or could I just have both scripts in there. Thanks heaps

Comment: you can leave it or drop it, as you wish. and could you accept my answer, I get 15 points for it. You know hoe to accept a answer. (at the start of my answer . on the left, there will be a right mark, just click on it)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you new to stackOverflow? If you accept my answer, I and you get points for that